# FSA Omega MegaEXO Press fit BB 19mm removal (non standard BB86)

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

Has anyone removed a 19mm spindle (Omega) Press fit bottom bracket without destroying it in the process?

I have watched http://www.fullspeedahead.tv/video/7006668/installation-of-megaexo-crankset-on and the tool mentioned #EE056 can't be found anywhere on the internet.

- That link is now broken. The best places to look seems to be http://www.fullspeedahead.com/support/technical-information-instructions/

I am not even sure that is for the 19mm version rather than the standard 24mm.

I understand I can take a punch/screwdriver and hammer it out of my frame, but the BB only has 1000km on it and I would like to reuse it in the winter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted FSA and was told no tool exists for pressing/removing the 19mm BB. So I proceeded with the cave man approach:

I used a long 3/8" extension (female side against the BB bearing) and hammer to knock out the left side, it came out easy.

The right side was a challenge with the same setup (it would not budge) , I ended up punching the bearing out of the BB shell.

I got the rest of the shell out with a 22mm deep socket and a short 1/2" extension and the same hammer technique. I would advise using a large socket that fits as soon as you get one side of the BB out.

The bearings/bb does not appear to be damaged and could be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. A friend sent me a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsDEP5Ljd3E) showing how to get this BB off.  I was mainly stuck without the confidence to really lean on the self-extracting crank, but the video had the next steps too.

To punch it out, I initially used a piece of scrapwood and a hammer.  For the last little bit I used a length of wooden dowel as a soft punch, again with a hammer.  I didn't have to hit it very hard (it was only about 6mm dowel, so that's just as well).

Answer (score -1):

Punching a bb out with a screwdriver or similar won't necessarily destroy it as long as you are careful.

Comment: It would be better to expand on this answer - what do you mean by careful, are there any tricks involved or do you just mean 'gentle tapping' rather than "percussion maintenance"?